# What is the correct way to use JavaScript to perform arithmetic on a DOM object?

Tags: javascript, dom

I've been trying to use the following code to add 1 from the value within the paragraph tags, but only get NaN as the output value:

```
<p id="myNumber">5</p>
<button onclick="increment()">Click</button>

<script>
function increment() {
    document.getElementById("myNumber").innerHTML = document.getElementById("myNumber").value + 1;
}
</script>
```

Can anyone say why this is outputting NaN?

Comment: 1. Use external events. (`addEventListener`) 2. It's `NaN` because DOM element values, `innerHTML` (do not use `innerHTML` here, you are not manipulating html, use `textContent`), text values, etc, are strings. 3. You need to parse them into numbers with `parseInt`, `Number()`, or even a unary conversion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is NaN because the `.value` of the `<p>` element is undefined. As a result you are doing this:

```
undefined + 1
```

Which is NaN. Get the value from the element using `.textContent` or `.innerHTML` depending on the structure, then use parseInt.

```
function increment() {
    document.getElementById("myNumber").textContent = parseInt(document.getElementById("myNumber").textContent,10) + 1;
}
```

Comment: `textContent` > `innerText`

Comment: @SterlingArcher - Yeah, minor lapse :) Edited to fix.

Comment: That's the Travis I know and love :D

Comment: Thanks, but what is the ,10 for after .textContent?

Comment: @JohnSmith It's parsing the string of `.textContent` with base 10

Comment: Thanks, I've selected yours as the best answer. Lastly though, why did you use .textContent rather than .innerHTML?

Comment: @JohnSmith `innerHTML` returns all HTML inside element, `textContent` returns text content.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the `innerText` (String) property of `myNumber` as an Integer:

```
document.getElementById("myNumber").innerText = parseInt(document.getElementById("myNumber").innerText) + 1;
```